# Loading combobox with json data in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs4

Im just trying to simply load some json data into my combobox using a basic data store. Here is my json data:

```js
{"services": [{"id": 1, "name": "dropbox"}, {"id": 2, "name": "facebook"}, {"id": 3, "name": "twitter"}]}
```

Here is my extjs 4 code:

```js
Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('ServiceList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'id', 'name'
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'ServiceList',
    proxy: {
        type: 'json',
        url: '/account/service/list',
        reader: {
            root: 'services',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    }
});
store.load();

Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    layout: 'auto',
    title: 'VAC',
    width: '100%',
    renderTo: 'vac-app-window',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        autoTabs:true,
        activeTab: 0,
        border:false,
        defaults: {autoHeight:true, bodyStyle:'padding:10px'},
        items: [{
            title: 'Data Services',
            items: [{
                xtype:'combo',
                store:store
            }]
        }]
    }]
});
});
```

Everything is being done on localhost so no cross domain stuff. I've been going through documentation but just can't figure out what im doing wrong.

As always any tips is much appreciated!

Update:

I edited some changes to the datastore and am getting a bit farther:

```js
Ext.define('ServiceList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name:'id', type:'int'},
        {name:'name', type:'string'}
    ]
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'ServiceList',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/account/service/list',
        reader: {
            root: 'services',
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
store.load();
```

Now when the page loads or I attempt to click the combobox the url it is addressing is:

GET /account/service/list?_dc=1318340688155&page=1&start=0&limit=25

From my reading this looks like jsonp but I dont know where the page,start, and limit params come from?

Update2:

Thanks to the help from Molecule Man I was able to sort this out:

```js
Ext.onReady(function(){

    Ext.define('ServiceList', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name:'id', type:'int'},
            {name:'name', type:'string'}
        ]
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'ServiceList',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            limitParam: undefined,
            startParam: undefined,
            paramName: undefined,
            pageParam: undefined,
            noCache:false,
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/account/service/list',
            reader: {
                root: 'services'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        layout: 'auto',
        title: 'VAC',
        width: '100%',
        renderTo: 'vac-app-window',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            autoTabs:true,
            activeTab: 0,
            border:false,
            defaults: {autoHeight:true, bodyStyle:'padding:10px'},
            items: [{
                title: 'Data Services',
                items: [{
                    xtype:'combo',
                    queryMode:'local',
                    emptyText: 'Select Service',
                    store:store,
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'id'
                }]
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

Hope this helps anyone else :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your combobox' config doesn't contain `displayField` (defaults to 'text') and `valueField`(defaults to displayField's value) which are required:

```
        items: [{
            xtype:'combo',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'id',
            store:store
        }]
```

Comment: Thanks, I added that however still no go.. does the proxy type have to be json or can it be jsonp?

Comment: @battlemidget, neither. It has to be 'ajax'.

Comment: i see this happening in my debug console:/account/service/list?_dc=1318340688155&page=1&start=0&limit=25 do i need to clear the params somehow?

Comment: @battlemidget, this params are being added by proxy automaticaly. If you want to remove them add `limitParam: undefined, startParam: undefined, pageParam: undefined, noCache: false` to your proxy's config.

Comment: ok that worked, now how do i get rid of : /account/service/list?query=

Comment: @battlemidget, add `queryMode: 'local',` to combo's config.